# How to check whether submitted is true or not from the reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am displaying a page loader for which I am getting the value from the reducer. If the submitted value is true then the loader is shown else the loader will be closed.
Since I am using multiple reducers I need to check each reducer whether submitted is true or not.

```
isLoading:
  state.agentState.submitted ||
  state.chitState.submitted ||
  state.chittiesState.submitted ||
  state.employeeState.submitted ||
  state.userState.submitted ||
  state.visitorState.submitted
```

[image]

How can i simplify above condition.

Comment: This is the way to do.i don't see any other better way.

Comment: You can add one more reducer that can manage only ui state separately and it will be having single property submitted that you can set when you want to show the loading icon.

Comment: @VikramSingh If i write a seperate reducer for the loader how will i pass the submitted value of each reducer to the newly created reducer

Comment: Whatever you are doing here will work with the ui reducer you just change the type of the action and dispatch it.

Comment: Instead of checking all statements with '||', you can use filter function from lodash to check in a "cleaner" way if there is any submitted value set on  true.
something like this: isLoading =  _.filter(state, yourFunctionHere) !== []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

I created a sandbox for you where you can see what I meant in my comment above:

https://codesandbox.io/s/p39zkx00zj

Don't forget to import lodash function:

```
import { some } from 'lodash';
```

Lodash in my **package.json**:

```
"lodash": "^4.17.5",
```

Just use some from lodash to loop through the state and see if you can find any state object with the key submitted === true. if it finds 1 it will return true and if it doens't it returns false.

```
 const isLoading = some(fakeState, item => item.submitted === true);
```

Comment: is it possible to use any instead of filter

Comment: so far as i know is that only possible on Arrays, and your state is an object, so you can only make it work with any if you use something like Object.keys. but filter from lodash handles that for you already, so i would advice you to stick with filter :D Is there any specific reason you want to use any? I am curious :)

Comment: Could use `Object.entries(state).some(([_,val])=>!!val.submitted)` as well.

Comment: @StephanHovius I have tried with isLoading: some(state, (item) => item.submitted === true)
and  i am getting the same result.
And i found it from here : _.any is an alias of _.some
https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide

Comment: @Nidhinkumar Oh yes, the some() function i know! that works too correct! I didn't know that alias :) some() is even better because it returns already a boolean for you :) well found! :D I shall update my answer!

Comment: @StephanHovius yes please